# Pointer to String conversion?

Tags: delphi

I am allocating the memory with GetMem (1028 bytes length), so I have an allocated Pointer.

Then I am reading the content and I know that there is e.g. 1028 bytes read.
how can I cast pointer, or convert it to a string?

Should I null terminate the content of the memory prior to conversion?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Delphi (unicode or ansi `string`)? From where the data comes, do you know beforehand that it is string or might there be other type of data as well?

Comment: Delphi-7. Data comes from tcp port. It is string. However even if there is some binary bytes it shouldn't be the problem for a string to hold them.

Comment: With binary data you cannot be sure there' not going to the a `0` value in there. Why not use code like `var buffer: string; begin SetLength(Buffer, 1028);` and then dump the stuff into that string. It will make it much easier to work with. You can access the individual bytes by using `buffer[20]`. For newer versions of Delphi you need to use `ansistring` of course.

Comment: Ok, let's assume it is a string. How to correctly cast it to a string?

Comment: In that case you can probably read the data directly into string variable, no need to go through intermediate buffer, ie `var buf: AnsiString; SetLength(buf, 1028); read(buf[1]);`. Key is to use `buf[1]` as the address of the buffer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`SetString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.SetString). Pass it a string variable, your pointer, and the string length (1028). Delphi strings are implicitly null-terminated, so the function will add that automatically (even if your buffer already has null bytes in it).

Better yet, set the length of the string and read your data directly into it instead of using an intermediary buffer. If you must use an intermediary buffer, you may as well use one that's statically sized to 1028 bytes instead of complicating your program with dynamic memory management.

Comment: SetString makes a copy of the content to a new place on the heap, right?

Comment: Yes. It certainly doesn't take ownership of the buffer, if that's what you're getting at. It has no way of knowing how an arbitrary buffer was allocated, so there's no way it could incorporate it into the requisite internal string data structures. A separate copy is therefore required.

Comment: Note that calling `SetLength()` over an existing string will re-allocate the string, i.e. move its old content to the new location, even if you'll not use this old content. So in practice, you should better use `SetString()`, even with `nil` as the memory buffer, or assign the previous string to '' before calling `SetLength()`.